Can we use Optuna to optimize YOLOv7's hyperparameters on a custom dataset?
I would like to use Optuna to optimize YOLOv7's hyperparameters like the learning rate, momentum, weight_decay, iou_t, etc. Is this possible?
I tried writing an objective function that would call the training script https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/train_aux.py with a hyperparameter file created in the previous step. This function would then parse its output to extract the mAP for the class of interest. This value would be reported to Optuna.
I was expecting this script to run for the number of trials and epochs I specified and then give me the optimal set of hyperparameters based on these runs.
